# Oracle SQL Expression to Sum Payments for Six Months based on Selected Month

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sum, period

Basically what I'm trying to do is calculate the average percentage of CreditPayments and the average percentage of CashPayments over a projected period (Lookback 3 months then total all paymnents of the correct type in the previous six months)

So if Average (During Correct Lookback Period) was = 75% Credit & 25% Cash then for my outstanding A/R for that month I could anticapte what % will be Credit & what % will be cash.  I'd like to run it for a 12 month period with the lookback changing for each MOS.

Right now my result is always 0, which is obviously wrong.  I know the initial inner query is correct; however, the problem happens when the outer query runs.  I think the problem lies with the T1. MOS, which I think is limiting the results.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
    T1.Facility Facility
    , T1.CustType CustType
    , T1.MOS MOS
    , SUM(CASE WHEN (T1.MOS BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(T1.MOS,-9) AND (ADD_MONTHS(T1.MOS,-3)-1) THEN T1.CredPmts ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN (T1.MOS BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(T1.MOS,-9) AND (ADD_MONTHS(T1.MOS,-3)-1) THEN T1.Charges ELSE 0 END)
    , SUM(CASE WHEN (T1.MOS BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(T1.MOS,-9) AND (ADD_MONTHS(T1.MOS,-3)-1) THEN T1.CashPmts ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN (T1.MOS BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(T1.MOS,-9) AND (ADD_MONTHS(T1.MOS,-3)-1) THEN T1.Charges ELSE 0 END)
FROM
(
SELECT
    T.FACILITY Facility
    , T.CUSTTYPE CustType
    , trunc(to_date(T.SERVICEDATE,'j'),'MONTH') MOS
    , SUM(CASE WHEN T.TYPE = 'C' THEN T.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) Charges
    , SUM(CASE WHEN (T.TYPE IN ('P1','62','12','75','P6','23') THEN T.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END CredPmts
    , SUM(CASE WHEN (T.TYPE IN ('92','57','P3','P9','26','39') THEN T.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END CashPmts
FROM TRANSTABLE T
WHERE
    T.FACILITY = '123'
    AND T.SERVICEDATE BETWEEN to_char(ADD_MONTHS(to_date('20120101', 'yyyymmdd'),-9), 'j') AND to_char(to_date('20121231', 'yyyymmdd'), 'j')
GROUP BY
    T.FACILITY
    , T.CUSTTYPE
    , trunc(to_date(T.SERVICEDATE,'j'),'MONTH')
)T1
GROUP BY
    T1.Facility
    , T1.CustType
    , T1.MOS
```

Comment: Could you supply some sample data from `TRANSTABLE`?  Or better yet, create a SQL Fiddle example with some data?  It looks like the issue is with how you are grouping the data, but it is hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are mismatched parenthesis in the `CASE WHEN` clause of the outer query:

`WHEN (T1.MOS BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(T1.MOS,-9) AND (ADD_MONTHS(T1.MOS,-3)-1)`**)**

all four places. Can you check it?

Comment: Changed and ran again.  Still returns zero.  Thanks for the quick reply!